# React updating state with big object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I need advice to work with large object in React.js.

Example:

```js
const [myObject, setMyObject] = React.useState({
  next_step: {
    id: 1575567015473,
    block_type: 'message',
    position: 'bottom',
    message: 'lorem ipsum',
    actions: {
      id: 1575562323,
      type: 'step_action',
      title: 'Show answers',
      description: 'Resend answer to another user',
      method: 'show_answer',
      points: 30
    },
    waiting: {
    interval: '4h50m',
    id: 1,
    position: 'right,
    next_step: {
      id: 3,
      position: 'bottom',
      block_type: 'message',
      message: 'lorem ipsum 3',
      waiting: null,
      next_step: null
    }
    }
    next_step: {
      id: 2,
      position: 'bottom',
      block_type: 'message',
      message: 'lorem ipsum 2',
      waiting: null,
      next_step: {
          id: 4,
          position: 'bottom',
          block_type: 'message',
          message: 'lorem ipsum 4',
          waiting: null,
          next_step: null
        }
      }
  }

});
```

I use recursion to render inputs with value message
After input changed I rerender my object.

Example:

```js
const findObject = (id, obj, fn) => {
  if (obj.id === id) {
    return fn(obj);
  }

  if (obj.waiting && obj.waiting.id) findObject(id, obj.waiting, fn);
  if (obj.next_step && obj.next_step.id) findObject(id, obj.next_step, fn);
  return obj;
};
  
const inputHandler = (value, id) => {
  const strFlowData = JSON.stringify(myObject);
  const newFlowData = JSON.parse(strFlowData);

  const inputUpdate = newObj => {
    const slackBlocks = newObj.body.blocks;
    const slackMassage = slackBlocks[0].text;
    slackMassage.text = value;
    return null;
  };

  findObject(id, newFlowData.next_step, newObj => inputUpdate(newObj));
  setMyObject(newFlowData);
};
```

Everything is working fine, but if this object becomes larger, Will I have problems  when the input changes? 
Maybe there is a better solution ?

Comment: Did you think about splitting your "big" object into several small that could be rendered by small PureComponent ? For instance, the steps can be a type itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a tree of pure components (or `React.useMemo`) and structure your website that only changed parts need to be checked for rerendering. 
That each input is a component on it's own and the check if it should be updated can be done while checking if the properties changed.

React does a good job at diffing the virtual dom, but if you can help and expect a performance impact otherwise, you might optimize. Most times it makes development easier, too :-)

Comment: I use react hooks and my component is simple function, but I think I must split up my inputs messages from object and update them and in the end when I submit form, I`ll update my object once. Now my object is being updated after every change.